# How to open a new JFrame without losing focus and editing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

By clicking on the button opens a new frame and until it is fully loaded (including execute a query in the database) I can not continue to work in the initial `JFrame`. (edit fields).

How to organize the opening frame (in the background, apparently) without losing focus and editing capabilities?

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: _I can not continue to work_ - then there's something wrong in the code you are not showing (hint, hint :-)

Comment: i mean i (from user's face) can't continue to work without delay caused by database searching.

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get--) the complete information with great examples. To solve the problem, it suffices to use class `SwingWorker`